# Categorized gallery

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, gallery

I'm trying to make categorized gallery for my blog. So far I've created datebase with tables: photos (photos_id, photos_gal_id, photos_link), galeries (galeries_id, galeries_title, galeries_description), and there are other tables, but not related to this problem (such as users, posts etc).

I've established connection with db through init file:

```
<?php


class init {
protected $db, $result;
private $rows;

public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost','root','hhpass','europa');
    }

public function query ($sql){
    $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }

public function rows(){
    for($x =1; $x<= $this->db->affected_rows; $x++){
        $this->rows[] = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        return $this->rows;
    }
}?>
```

Then I get the data from DB through:

```
class Galeries extends Init {
public function fetchGaleries(){

    //query db
    $this->query("SELECT photos_id,
                photos.photos_gal_id as 'group',
                GROUP_CONCAT(photos_link) as link, galeries.galeries_title, galeries.galeries_description, galeries.galeries_id
                FROM photos
                INNER JOIN galeries
                ON galeries.galeries_id=photos.photos_gal_id
                GROUP BY photos.photos_gal_id 
                ORDER BY galeries.galeries_id ASC");        
    //return
    return $this->rows();
    }

}
```

So far it works fine.. when I call this function in seperate file with:

```
$galeries_a = new Galeries();
$gals_x = $galeries_a->fetchGaleries();
```

and if I use the

```
foreach($gals_x as $gals_y){

echo $gals_y['group'];

}
```

it does fine and lists galeries(categories): 1,2,3,4. Which are the DB-s groups, as defined by query.

NOW, the problem is, how to make the links show up inside these groups (only links that belong to that group). 
I know I have to make UL/LI listings in HTML, and that is not the problem, that part works, the problem is the PHP part :)

To sum, it should look like this.

- 1 First Gallery

  - Link One
  - Link Two etc
- 2 Second Gallery

  - Link One
  - Link Two etc
- 3 Third Gallery

  - Link One
  - Link Two etc
- 4 Fourth Gallery

  - Link One
  - Link Two etc

I've tried everything: while, foreach, everything, cannot get it to work properly.